# Uploading and installing app from Eclipse makes phone reboot

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm developing multiple apps, but with this one app the phone sometimes reboots when I try to run the last build via Eclipse.

This is the logcat right before the reboot, the application is not yet installed (Eclipse console says "Installing MyApplication":

```
12-29 21:04:53.375: E/PeopleApp(30398): DialerService connected !
12-29 21:04:53.445: E/ExternalAccountType(30398): Unsupported attribute readOnly
12-29 21:04:53.505: E/ExternalAccountType(30398): Unsupported attribute readOnly
12-29 21:04:53.555: E/ExternalAccountType(30398): Unsupported attribute readOnly
12-29 21:04:53.615: E/ExternalAccountType(30398): Unsupported attribute readOnly
12-29 21:04:53.666: E/ExternalAccountType(30398): Unsupported attribute readOnly
12-29 21:04:54.396: E/VoldProcessKiller(204): Process system_server (26373) has open file /mnt/asec/com.haarman.whopayswhat-2/pkg.apk in /mnt/asec/com.haarman.whopayswhat-2
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/SurfaceTexture(209): [StatusBar] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/SurfaceTextureClient(26503): dequeueBuffer failed (No such device)
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/ViewRootImpl(26503): IllegalArgumentException locking surface
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/ViewRootImpl(26503): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/ViewRootImpl(26503):  at android.view.Surface.lockCanvasNative(Native Method)
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/ViewRootImpl(26503):  at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java)
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/ViewRootImpl(26503):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java)
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/ViewRootImpl(26503):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java)
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/ViewRootImpl(26503):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java)
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/ViewRootImpl(26503):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/ViewRootImpl(26503):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/ViewRootImpl(26503):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/ViewRootImpl(26503):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/ViewRootImpl(26503):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/ViewRootImpl(26503):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/ViewRootImpl(26503):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
12-29 21:04:54.617: E/ViewRootImpl(26503):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 21:04:54.987: E/installd(215): eof
12-29 21:04:54.987: E/installd(215): failed to read size
12-29 21:04:55.327: E/InputQueue-JNI(26503): channel '411ae9f8 StatusBar (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
12-29 21:04:55.327: E/InputQueue-JNI(26645): channel '41356a40 com.android.htccontacts/com.android.htccontacts.DialerTabActivity (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
12-29 21:04:55.337: E/InputQueue-JNI(26503): channel '41138d70 NavigationBar (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
12-29 21:04:55.337: E/InputQueue-JNI(26503): channel '40d93408 StatusBarExpanded (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
12-29 21:04:55.337: E/InputQueue-JNI(26956): channel '413254b0 com.teslacoilsw.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
12-29 21:04:55.367: E/InputQueue-JNI(26503): channel '414c3db0 TrackingView (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
12-29 21:04:55.367: E/InputQueue-JNI(26503): channel '4154af30 com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
12-29 21:04:55.367: E/InputQueue-JNI(27444): channel '413020c8 com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
12-29 21:04:55.668: E/NetlinkEvent(204): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.668: E/NetlinkEvent(204): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.718: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.718: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.718: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.718: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.728: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.738: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.738: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.738: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.738: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.738: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.738: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.738: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.738: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.748: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.748: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.748: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.748: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.748: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.748: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.758: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.758: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.758: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.758: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.758: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.758: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.758: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.758: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.758: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.758: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.758: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.758: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.758: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.758: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.768: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.778: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.788: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.788: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.788: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.788: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.788: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.788: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.788: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.788: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.788: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.788: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.788: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.788: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.798: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.808: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.808: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:55.808: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_NAME' not found
12-29 21:04:55.808: E/NetlinkEvent(30431): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'SWITCH_STATE' not found
12-29 21:04:56.639: E/alsa_ucm(30422): Unknown type: p  
12-29 21:04:56.789: E/(30422): actp_diag_init: call diag init function with 40E43215
12-29 21:04:56.789: E/(30422): actp_diag_init: diag init failed
12-29 21:04:57.430: E/PhonePolicy(30424): Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
12-29 21:05:00.002: E/HtcBootAnimation(30467): Could not find width. 
12-29 21:05:00.002: E/HtcBootAnimation(30467): Could not find height. 
12-29 21:05:00.002: E/HtcBootAnimation(30467): Could not find framerate. 
12-29 21:05:00.002: E/HtcBootAnimation(30467): Could not find part1. 
12-29 21:05:00.002: E/HtcBootAnimation(30467): Could not find part2. 
12-29 21:05:00.012: E/HtcBootAnimation(30467): Could not find part3. 
12-29 21:05:00.012: E/HtcBootAnimation(30467): SQL error: unable to open database file
12-29 21:05:00.012: E/HtcBootAnimation(30467): sqlite result: 14, errno: 13, Permission denied
12-29 21:05:01.864: E/MediaPlayerService(30422): getService( activity ): returned null
12-29 21:05:01.864: E/OMXMaster(30422): A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one.
```

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="20121222alpha" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:name="com.myapp.utils.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />


    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

As said, I'm not experiencing this with any other apps. I have no idea where to look for a solution for this.

***EDIT***
This is the log from `adb shell cat /proc/kmsg`:

```
<6>[39753.677547] [K][PM] CPU1: msm_pm_power_collapse: change clock rate (old ra
te = 0)
<6>[39754.592334] mdp4_overlay_pipe_free: pipe=c0c760a8 ndx=3 stage 2 mixer 0
<6>[39754.592487] mdp4_overlay_pipe_free: pipe=c0c762b8 ndx=4 stage 3 mixer 0
<6>[39754.592609] mdp4_overlay_pipe_free: pipe=c0c75e98 ndx=2 stage 4 mixer 0
<4>[39754.593525] mdp4_overlay_update_layers: unstaging pipe ndx=3
<4>[39754.593525] mdp4_overlay_update_layers: unstaging pipe ndx=4
<4>[39754.593555] mdp4_overlay_update_layers: unstaging pipe ndx=2
<4>[39754.593555] mdp4_overlay_update_layers: mask=0000F0FF new layermixer_cfg=0
0000100
<6>[39754.608083] mdp4_overlay_req2pipe: pipe=c0c760a8 ndx=3 num=2 zorder=2 mixe
r 0 format = b
<6>[39754.627250] mdp4_overlay_req2pipe: pipe=c0c762b8 ndx=4 num=3 zorder=3 mixe
r 0 format = 9
<6>[39754.631187] mdp4_overlay_req2pipe: pipe=c0c75e98 ndx=2 num=1 zorder=4 mixe
r 0 format = 9
<6>[39755.921130] [SMD] smsm_change_state b29
<6>[39755.925556] [SMD] smsm_change_state 929
<6>[39755.970237] [SMD] smsm_change_state f29
<6>[39755.970390] [SMD] smsm_change_state d29
<6>[39756.043761] [SMD] smsm_change_state b29
<6>[39756.043914] [SMD] smsm_change_state f29
<6>[39756.044097] [SMD] smsm_change_state d29
<6>[39756.510387] call alarm, type 2, func alarm_triggered+0x0/0xa0, 84242213000
000 (s 84242213000000)
<6>[39757.486184] [LED]Setting amber off_timer to 0 min 0 sec +
<6>[39757.486368] [LED]pm8xxx_led_gpio_set, bank:0, brightness:0
<6>[39757.486642] [LED]pm8xxx_led_blink_store: bank 0 blink 0
<6>[39757.486856] [LED]Setting green off_timer to 0 min 0 sec +
<6>[39758.496867] [SMD] smsm_change_state b29
<>378479][M]ss_hnesae99<>378479][M]ss_hnesae99_e iecc6a d= tg  ie
6[95.028 d4oelypp_re iecc6b d= tg  ie
6[95.030 d4oelypp_re iecc59 d= tg  ie
4[95.064 d4oelyudt_aes ntgn ienx3<>378720]mp_vra_paelyr:usaigpp d=
4[95.065 d4oelyudt_aes ntgn ienx2<>378723]mp_vra_paelyr:ms=000Fnwlyrie_f=0010<6>
[39758.968223] [K][PM] CPU1: msm_pm_power_collapse: change clock rate (old rate
= 0)
<6>[39759.053253] alarm_release: clear alarm, pending 0
<6>[39759.054687] alarm_release: clear alarm, pending 0
<6>[39759.054962] alarm_release: clear alarm, pending 0
<6>[39759.055237] alarm_release: clear alarm, pending 0
<6>[39759.385833] [LS][cm3629] lightsensor_release
<6>[39759.408052] [SMD] smsm_change_state f29
<6>[39759.410372] [SMD] smsm_change_state d29
<6>[39759.498515] request_suspend_state: wakeup (0->0) at 39756372649691 (2012-1
2-29 21:03:46.151247964 UTC)
<3>[39759.522107] init: untracked pid 29490 exited
<3>[39759.544265] init: untracked pid 31171 exited
<3>[39759.547439] init: untracked pid 31211 exited
<3>[39759.607320] init: untracked pid 29489 exited
<3>[39759.607778] init: untracked pid 29884 exited
<3>[39759.619131] init: untracked pid 32538 exited
<3>[39759.649285] init: untracked pid 29739 exited
<3>[39759.651757] init: untracked pid 29752 exited
<6>[39759.695096] genlock: genlock_release_lock: Releasing a handle that still h
olds lock (2)
<3>[39759.696256] init: untracked pid 29642 exited
<6>[39759.704100] genlock: genlock_release_lock: Releasing a handle that still h
olds lock (2)
<3>[39759.705015] init: untracked pid 30198 exited
actd e!<>370730][U]hcaosi:oe
6[96.013 AD t-cutc upr opnns x
6[96.014 AD t-cutc ees
<3>[39760.868452] init: untracked pid 467 exited
<3>[39760.869185] init: untracked pid 29840 exited
<3>[39760.869886] init: untracked pid 30039 exited
<3>[39760.870527] init: untracked pid 29791 exited
<3>[39760.871321] init: untracked pid 30506 exited
<6>[39760.871474] [SMD] smsm_change_state b29
<3>[39760.872114] init: untracked pid 30667 exited
<3>[39760.872816] init: untracked pid 30826 exited
<3>[39760.873366] init: untracked pid 30855 exited
<3>[39760.873885] init: untracked pid 30905 exited
<3>[39760.874495] init: untracked pid 31157 exited
<6>[39760.875960] [SMD] smsm_change_state 929
<3>[39760.887344] init: untracked pid 32716 exited
<3>[39760.887802] init: untracked pid 32739 exited
<3>[39760.888290] init: untracked pid 302 exited
<3>[39760.888748] init: untracked pid 324 exited
<3>[39760.889206] init: untracked pid 380 exited
<3>[39760.889725] init: untracked pid 393 exited
<3>[39760.890213] init: untracked pid 424 exited
<3>[39760.890671] init: untracked pid 453 exited
<3>[39760.892044] init: untracked pid 481 exited
<3>[39760.893631] init: untracked pid 407 exited
<6>[39760.961051] [SMD] smsm_change_state f29
<6>[39760.961234] [SMD] smsm_change_state b29
<6>[39760.961417] [SMD] smsm_change_state 929
<6>[39760.961966] [SMD] smsm_change_state f29
<6>[39760.962089] [SMD] smsm_change_state d29
<6>[39760.962241] [SMD] smsm_change_state b29
<6>[39760.962516] [SMD] smsm_change_state f29
<6>[39760.962668] [SMD] smsm_change_state d29
<6>[39761.268666] [K][PM] CPU1: msm_pm_power_collapse: change clock rate (old ra
te = 0)
<6>[39762.186047] [SMD] smsm_change_state b29
<6>[39762.186200] [SMD] smsm_change_state 929
<6>[39763.666071] [LS][cm3629] lightsensor_open
<6>[39763.666132] [LS][cm3629] lightsensor_ioctl LIGHTSENSOR_IOCTL_GET_ENABLED,
enabled 1
<6>[39763.746096] [PS][cm3629] psensor_open
<6>[39763.746248] [PS][cm3629] psensor_ioctl cmd 1
<6>[39763.882827] mdp4_overlay_req2pipe: pipe=c0c760a8 ndx=3 num=2 zorder=2 mixe
r 0 format = b
<6>[39763.886123] [COMP] Compass enable
<6>[39763.886306] [GYRO][PANASONIC] Open device node:ewtzmu2hal times.
<6>[39763.886398] [GYRO][PANASONIC] Release ewtzmu2hal, remainder is  times.
<6>[39763.886520] [COMP][AKM8975] [COMP] Compass disable
<6>[39764.006068] [GYRO][PANASONIC] Open device node:ewtzmu2hal times.
<6>[39764.006221] [GYRO][PANASONIC] Release ewtzmu2hal, remainder is  times.
<6>[39764.006557] [PS][cm3629] psensor_ioctl cmd 2
<6>[39764.006679] [PS][cm3629] psensor_disable
<6>[39764.006740] [PS][cm3629] psensor_disable: already disabled
<6>[39764.006801] [PS][cm3629] psensor_release
<6>[39764.006923] [PS][cm3629] psensor_disable
<6>[39764.007015] [PS][cm3629] psensor_disable: already disabled
<6>[39764.007137] [LS][cm3629] lightsensor_ioctl LIGHTSENSOR_IOCTL_ENABLE, value
 = 0
<6>[39764.007198] [LS][cm3629] lightsensor_disable
<6>[39764.010067] [LS][cm3629] lightsensor_release
<6>[39765.915850] [AUD] snd_soc_qdsp6: msm_pcm_routing_process_audio: reg 2 val
0 set 1
<6>[39765.916583] [AUD] board_ville_audio: ville_get_q6_effect_mode: mode 0
<6>[39765.938374] [AUD] board_ville_audio: ville_get_q6_effect_mode: mode 0
<6>[39765.938801] [AUD] q6asm: q6asm_open_write: change to HTC_POPP_TOPOLOGY
<6>[39765.966361] [AUD] board_ville_audio: ville_get_q6_effect_mode: mode 0
```

Comment: Are you experiencing it with one kind of a phone or with multiple ones? What kind of phone / phone version / Android version are you running?

Comment: is this problem seen with an emulator as well?

Comment: I'm currently testing this on an HTC One S with ViperOneS rom. I will try it out on a Legend next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a problem with the phones firmware. This might hapen if you want to use a feature not really supported by your phone (like playing unsupported media, using unsupported OpenGL commands, etc.). The error message logcat shows clearly indicates something has destroyed the Surface, so it's some kind of a drawing error.

If your phone is rooted you might want to look at the continuous kernel log by typing:

```
adb shell su -c "cat /proc/kmsg"
```

or if root adb access is enabled simply by:

```
adb root
adb shell cat /proc/kmsg
```

If your phone is not rooted you can still try to use `dmesg`:

```
adb shell dmesg
```

but it won't print the kernel log continuously, so you might miss a few important lines that directly lead to the restart of the phone, so you might want to root the phone to get those few missing lines.

Comment: I've added the `adb shell cat /proc/kmsg` log to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't really show anything. Does your code use any hardware related things in it's main activity? (OpenGL, sensors, audio, etc.)